# Не правильно отображается прямоугольники

Tags: qt, qml

У меня есть 26 на 26 окно, его нужно заполнить прямоугольниками , и прямоугольники некоторые больше других, и через это между прямоугольниками есть пространство, а мне не нужно чтобы оно было. 
Красным выделено те прямоугольники которые больше остальных.
Черным выделено то пространство что не заполнено.

Первый вопрос: Подскажите как убрать его?

Второй вопрос: я вручную все заполняю, и до концы це наполнил еще. Можно както не вручну заполнить? Думал фором, но int не видет((
исходник:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
ApplicationWindow
{
     visible: true
     width: 2200
     height: 2200
     title: qsTr("Game")
     Rectangle {color: "black"}
     Grid
     {
       x: 383
       y: 0
       width: 1321
       height: 1027
       columns: 26
       spacing: 0
       Rectangle { color: "blue"; width: 64; height: 64  }
       Rectangle { color: "white"; width: 32; height: 32 }
       Rectangle { color: "green"; width: 32; height: 32
       ....................
       Rectangle { color: "blue"; width: 64; height: 64  }
       Rectangle { color: "green"; width: 32; height: 32 }
       Rectangle { color: "yellow"; width: 32; height: 32 }
       Rectangle { color: "white"; width: 32; height: 32 }
       Rectangle { color: "green"; width: 32; height: 32 }
       .....................
       Rectangle { color: "white"; width: 32; height: 32 }
       Rectangle { color: "yellow"; width: 32; height: 32 }
       Rectangle { color: "green"; width: 32; height: 32 }
     }
}
```

[image: my programa]

Comment: Так как Вы хотите, не получится сделать с `Grid`. Как Вы себе представляете, чтобы в сетке отдна строка наезжала на другую? Нужно использовать другой layout(а точнее их сочетание, скорее всего.

Comment: @ixSci, GridLayout попробовал.  там геморроя много. И  размеры  не пойми какие выходят

Comment: У Вас в коде и есть GridLayout. Навскидку я могу сказать, что для того, чтобы сделать то, что Вы хотите, Вам придётся писать свой layout, что, в целом не сложно, но потратить время придётся.